# calculation wave function

Tags: fourier-series, interpolation

I have a bunch of points from a segment (~1.5 periods) of a wave. The wave looks like a cosinus wave, but it isn't. The length between the left maximum and the minimum is shorter than the length between the right maximum and the minimum. Also the maximums differ in heights.

[image: wave]

I want to describe the wave as a function as accurate as possible and interpolate the next period.

I guess the wave is some overlapping of sinus and cosinus functions. 
Is a Fourier series the correct tool to use, and how can I calculate the coefficient from the points? If not, what would be a better way?

Comment: If you are trying to identify the main frequency components, and your sample locations are evenly spaced, then the first thing to look at is the magnitude of the DFT.

Comment: Without more prior knowledge, we don't know how the function behaves outside the segment where you took measurements.  Maybe it does something crazy.  Is it possible that the underlying signal is a true cosine wave and the aberrations are just due to noise?  1.5 periods doesn't seem like enough to meaningfully establish a trend.  What if you just fit a cosine wave to these data points (as nearly as you can, in some sense) and declare that you're done?

Comment: The wave will behave in an equal way. Mostly. There may are some minor differences (maximums are a little bit higher, ...). 
At the moment I interpolate the wave with a cosinus, but this is not a satisfactory solution.